# Go's garbage collector is deleting ZeroMQ sockets when in use

Tags: go, sockets, garbage-collection, runtime-error, zeromq

I am developing a distributed system uisng ZeroMQ and Go. It's like a distributed ledger so you can get the contects and append. I have automated clients making GET and ADD requests. The program runs fine for a couple of seconds but then crashes with the error "panic: socket operation on non-socket".

I tried turning off the garbage collector using debug.SetGCPercent(-1) but im sure this solution is not entirely correct.
This is the server initialization code

```
package server

import (
    "backend/config"
    "backend/gset"
    "backend/tools"

    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
)

type Server struct {
    Zctx           *zmq.Context
    Peers          map[string]*zmq.Socket
    Receive_socket zmq.Socket
    Id             string
    Gset           map[string]string
    Port           string
    My_init    map[string]bool
    My_echo    map[string]bool
    My_vote    map[string]bool
    Peers_echo map[string]bool
    Peers_vote map[string]bool
}

func CreateServer(node config.Node, peers []config.Node, zctx *zmq.Context) *Server {
    id := node.Host + node.Port
    port := node.Port
    server_sockets := make(map[string]*zmq.Socket)
    my_gset := gset.Create()
    my_init := make(map[string]bool)
    my_echo := make(map[string]bool)
    my_vote := make(map[string]bool)
    peers_echo := make(map[string]bool)
    peers_vote := make(map[string]bool)
    receive_socket, _ := zctx.NewSocket(zmq.ROUTER)
    receive_socket.Bind("tcp://*:" + node.Port)
    tools.Log(id, "Bound tcp://*:"+node.Port)

    // Connect my dealer sockets to all other servers' router
    for i := 0; i < len(peers); i++ {
        s, _ := zctx.NewSocket(zmq.DEALER)
        s.SetIdentity(id)
        s.Connect("tcp://localhost:" + peers[i].Port)
        // append socket to socket list
        server_sockets["tcp://localhost:"+peers[i].Port] = s
    }

    return &Server{
        Peers:          server_sockets,
        Receive_socket: *receive_socket,
        Id:             id,
        Port:           port,
        Gset:           my_gset,
        My_init:        my_init,
        My_echo:        my_echo,
        My_vote:        my_vote,
        Peers_echo:     peers_echo,
        Peers_vote:     peers_vote,
    }
}
```

And this is the function that contols the server

```
func Normal_listener_task(s *server.Server) {
    for {
        message, err := s.Receive_socket.RecvMessage(0)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(zmq.AsErrno(err))
            panic(err)
        }
        messaging.HandleMessage(s, message)
    }
}
```

The entire code is in my github [here](https://github.com/loukaspapalazarou/Thesis/tree/main/BFT-Distributed-G-Set-Local)

If anyone knows why this is happening you will save my thesis. Thank you

Comment: If this is actually happening as you say, it means the code is invalid and incorrectly using `unsafe` in some way, but if that were the case I would expect to find open issues with the package already . Are you checking all errors? (you are ignoring at least one in this code example) The other possibility is that you have a data race -- have you tested this with the race detector?

Comment: Hey Jim thank you for your reply. I'm quite new to Go programming so bare with me. I do not use the unsafe package anywhere in my code if that is what you are reffering to. You are right i am not checking all the errors but the snippet is just from the initialization but the program runs fine for a couple of seconds and then crashes so its probably not that but i will check out the other errors for sure. And I have not used a race detectror since I do not really know how to use Go's. However I am pretty sure its not a race condition since each server has its own namespace.

Comment: You don't need to be using `unsafe` yourself, the `zmq` uses it quite a bit because it interfaces with the C zmq bindings, but again I would expect invalid use of pointers to have been noticed already. Go has no exceptions, so never ignore errors or you may end up with unexpected behavior that is hard to pinpoint, like this case. There is plenty of documentation on using the race detector,  https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector, which is an easy thing to check though it may be less useful when most of the work is done in C.

Comment: I have checked all the errors and none of them seem to be the problem. I guess my main question would be: If the problem is indeed a race condition, why does the program work perfectly then the GC is turned off? Or am I missing something regarding the race condition?

Comment: Checking for a race is just an easy way to eliminate a class of common errors, not necessarily the problem. Where is the panic even happening? What value /method/function call is panicking?

Comment: You are correct, I will check the race docs and try to eliminate this possibility.
The panic occures in the Normal_listener_task function when calling message, err := s.Receive_socket.RecvMessage(0). My theory is that for some reason the GC collects the socket and therefore the RecvMessage(0) panics with "panic: socket operation on non-socket"

Comment: Oh, your server is storing a `zmq.Socket`, but `NewSocket` returns a `*zmq.Socket`. You should never dereference a pointer and store the value like that, the pointer is likely required for a reason (though I didn't confirm), and even if the pointer isn't technically needed, there's no reason to do that. You may be corrupting things be copying a value which you are not intended to copy, or acting an a stale copy of the socket structure.

Comment: Holy mother of jesus that was the problem. I forgot the pointer on the server struct. Thank you soo much man I have been stuck there for weeks!! Again thanks I wish you the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was declaring the receive_socket with `Receive_socket zmq.Socket` when it should have been `*Receive_socket zmq.Socket`. The pointer was just a copy, therefore being considered trash by the GC.

Comment: More specifically; the Go garbage collector is fully precise, so it's not going to collect reachable data structures, however the the zmq library sets a finalizer on the pointer which is going to close the socket when the pointer is checked by the GC.